# variable scope within a module

Tags: python

I am being stupid and have read numerous posts or articles but I don't understand the scope of variables in Python.

So I have a function in a module & I want to have a constant variable that is available to any function that is the module.

```
**MyModule.py**

_MYCONST = 65.2

def MyFunc():
    return _MYCONST
```

However when I run MyFunc in the console all I get is,

```
Out[12]: <function MyModule.MyFunc>
```

Why am I getting this output and not 65.2?

Comment: call `MyFunc()` like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how did you "run" the function? It seems to me like you only wrote Myfunc and forgot the parenthesis. Remember that functions need to be called in a certain way to actually run them.

Try "MyFunc()"

Answer (score 2):

The return value of the function is returned in the calling function.
The function call needs to take () and the necessary parameters.
When you only use the function name, it is a function object.
According to this, there can be a little trick.

```
def my_function()
    return 'value'
f=my_function
print(f())
#result: value
```

You can give the function an alias, that is a reference.Use this function with an alias.
**This is the underlying principle of using closures.**
hope my answer can help you!